# R: Using piping to pass a single argument to multiple locations in a function

Tags: r, piping, magrittr

I am attempting to exclusively use piping to rewrite the following code (using babynames data from babynames package:

```
library(babynames)
library(dplyr)

myDF <- babynames %>% 
group_by(year) %>% 
summarise(totalBirthsPerYear = sum(n))

slice(myDF, seq(1, nrow(myDF), by = 20))
```

The closest I have gotten is this code (not working):

```
myDF <- babyNames %>% 
group_by(year) %>% 
summarise(totalBirthsPerYear = sum(n)) %>% 
slice( XXX, seq(1, nrow(XXX), by = 20))
```

where XXX is meant to be passed via pipes to slice, but I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The last line should be `slice(seq(1, nrow(.), by = 20))`. You don't need the first `XXX` because the output of `summarise` is already automatically piped into `slice`. The second `XXX` is replaced by `.`, where `.` is the "pronoun" used to refer to the data frame that was piped into the function.

Comment: spectacular, thanks so much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can reference piped data in a different position in the function by using the `.` In your case:

```
myDF2 <- babynames %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarize(totalBirthsPerYear = sum(n)) %>%
    slice(seq(1, nrow(.), by = 20))
```

Answer (score 9):

*Not sure if this should be opened as a separate question & answer but in case anybody arrives here as I did looking for the answer to the **MULTIPLE** in the title:
**R: Using piping to pass a single argument to multiple locations in a function***

Using the `.` from Andrew's answer in multiple places also achieves this.

*[example]* To get the last element of a vector `vec <- c("first", "middle", "last")`
 we could use this code.

```
vec[length(vec)]
```

Using piping, the following code achieves the same thing:

```
vec %>% .[length(.)]
```

*Hopefully this is helpful to others as it would have helped me (I knew about the `.` but couldn't get it working in multiple locations).*

Comment: It doesn't work for me in this example:
`vec %>% lead(., 0) + lead(., 1)`. I get `Error in vec_size(x) : object '.' not found`